# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on start

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android developing. Last week everything worked fine, but since yesterday it is not possible to open any project and I have no idea what could be the reason. Also, Google couldn't help me. Even if I start a completely new project I get the same error message. Uninstalling Android Studio and deleting all relevant folders of Android didn't help as well.

(I'm using Java and not Kotlin).

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: Cause: startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.AbstractKotlinGradleModelBuilder

    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.AbstractKotlinGradleModelBuilder
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1109)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:649)
        ...
```

Comment: you should add your gradle conf to the post, it might have something to do with how you include the library

Comment: Hello Joachim, what exactly do you mean with the gradle conf?

Comment: do you mean the code of build.gradle which is included in every project?

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been solved. I have simply modified the path of Android Studios when I installed it again and now its fine.